# GraphQL (node over REST) Nested Arguments Missing from Arguments Object

Tags: api, graphql, nested, arguments

I have a GraphQL question. I am running it over a REST API and all appears to be working apart from nested arguments.

I have this query...

```
query {
    Document(reference: "123ABC") {
        id
        reference
        Parts(id: "1212") {
            id
            content
        }
    }
}
```

And this is against the following schema...

```
schema {
    query: Query
}

type Document {
    id: ID
    reference: String
    name: String
    Parts(id: ID): [Part]
}

type Part {
    id: ID
    content: String
}
    
type Query {
    Document(id: ID, reference: String): Document!
    Documents: [Document]
    Part(id: ID): Part!
    Parts: [Part]
}
```

Now for the most part this setup is working, i can use a reference or ID to match a single document, or get all documents and also have nested parts. The issue is when i try to use arguments on the nested 'Parts'. The id I am setting on Parts model is not coming through to the args on the nested rootValue.

```
const rootValue = {
    Document: async (args) => await document.model(args),
    Documents: async (args) => await document.models(args),
    Part: async (args) => await part.one(args),
    Parts: async (args) => await part.many(args)
};
    
return graphql({ source: request.body.query, variableValues: 
request.body.variables, schema, rootValue });
```

So i pass in schema, variableValues is in case i want to send in variables separately (also not working) in this case undefined.

args passed into each model only has the following in it...

```
{
   "reference": "123ABC"
}
```

With no sign of the other argument from Parts(id: "123"), anyone have any idea where im messing up, why the other argument would be missing, am i looking in the wrong place...

I can dump out another var from the methods on rootValue, looks like a definition that graphql is using, the values are in there deep inside i can search for the value, but why they not being passed to args?

thanks people!

Paul

Answer (score 0):

OK, I had a thought, and did this...

```
    Document: async (args) => {
        console.log(4, JSON.stringify(args))
        return { 
            ...await document.model(args),
            Parts: async (ffs) => {
                console.log(5, JSON.stringify(ffs));
            }
        }
    },
```

And up it popped.... i see whats happening now, its passing the args out based on location in the rootValue.

I get the first arg in the first console log only and the second in the second console log only...

Documentation around the web is a little sparse in this.

I think i need to re-jig my code now, to sub query on nested models instead of returning one big nested dataset.